# tar removing leading '/' from member names

Tags: linux, tar

I got an error when I append > `/dev/null` to tar command, anyone know what's going on in second example?

good:

```
 tar -cvf $kname /var/www
```

bad:

```
 tar -cvf $kname /var/www > /dev/null

 error:tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

Comment: Am I the only one who is bothered by the fact that the message from tar has two different quotes? The first one is a backtick, and the second one is a single quote.

Comment: See also [tar: Removing leading \`/' from member names](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59243)

Comment: Unfortunately tar prints it at the beginning of the building of the archive so you will miss this message if the screen scrolls up.

Comment: @DanCron That is probably taken from LaTeX quotes styling. (I like it! :D ) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/quotes-in-latex#10672

Comment: @Campa I think you're onto something. But if they chose to use LaTeX style quotes, wouldn't they use two backticks before, and then two single quotes after `\`\`/''`?

Comment: The short reason this happened is not because $kname had a leading slash (if that were so, then good would also get the error), but rather because ''/var/www'' had a leading slash.  Tar spits this error for both ouput and source.  The dangers of running -P below therefore don't apply to your use case, because you are not changing the source target.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "good" version is also displaying the same message you've just missed it.

If you don't like the behaviour, search for "leading", in manual. First hit:

```
-P, --absolute-names
       don't strip leading '/'s from file names
```

Comment: the good version can be executed successfully. but the bad versin gave me the error "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names". i am not quite understand this error message, how do i resolve the error?

Comment: The "bad" version can be executed just as successfully. As I said, both display the same message.

Comment: adding "-P" works, see: tar -cvf test.tar -P /var/www > /dev/null, thanks

Comment: note: you probably don't want that... simply ignore the message.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: why not?

Comment: @parvus because untarring that file would untar it into the absolute path it was tarred from, possibly overwriting very valuable files. without the leading slash, it untars relative to ./

Comment: This does not work for me. I do not wish to alter the tar command in any way, I wish to keep it as it is, creating the very same archive it already does and only stop outputting the damned "Removing whatever" line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

This is because your file (`$kname`) has leading `/`.

To fix that, you may specify `-C` to change the directory, instead of specifying full path of the archive file.

Comment: while `-P` works out as a workaround, `-C` is probably more what you want.

Comment: `-C` has no effect with `-c`

Answer (score 5):

It might be best to leave your files without the '/' in the backup and just ignore the error message.  Tar does this as a safety precaution, because if you untar the file, it will automatically place the files back in the original directory.  This can be dangerous and most people want to avoid this.  Personally, I would be happy with the fact that it removed the '/' and then your restore will be relative and not absolute directory path.  Then you can manually move the files into the right place, or a different place.  Just posting this so people are aware and don't inadvertently replace their original files.

Comment: my version of tar does not extract an archive created with -P (--absolute-names) to the original location. this is only true for untar with argument -P

Answer (score 0):

my version of tar does not extract an archive created with -P (--absolute-names) to the original location. this is only true for untar with argument -P