# tar: Removing leading `/' from member names showing in tarfile.add (python)

Tags: python-3.x, tarfile

Getting the following warning while creating .tar file of a folder that consists of folders and files:

> "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names"

Tarfile is created with the following code snippet.I have **sample** folder in my current directory which I am using to add files in tar file But, I want to get rid of the above warning:

```
def create_tarball(self, dir_name):    
        try:
           with tarfile.open("example.tar", "w:tar") as tar:
                    tar.add("./sample/"+dir_name, arcname=os.path.basename(".sample/"))
        except Exception as e:
                raise(e)
```

I have seen the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929315/tar-removing-leading-from-member-names) for the command line like using -C. But how can I implement it in this python code?

Comment: Can you show the output of `tar -tf <filename>.tar` for one of the archives created by your code? It's not clear from your question why there are files in your archive with a leading `/`.

Comment: Please have a look at the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module for platform-agnostic path handling. Use forward-slashes as path separators; Windows nowadays understands those as well.